# setPlainText calling focusOutEvent in QGraphicsSimpleTextItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

Im overridding the focusOutEvent in QGraphicsTextItem

```
void EditTextItem::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
    emit lostFocus(this);
    QGraphicsTextItem::focusOutEvent(event);
}
```

when the user edit the text item im saving the edited text to a file. before user edits the text im calling to show the previous text 
setPlainText("Old Data")
which in turn calling focusOutEvent() of GraphicsTextItem and lostFocus() signal has been emitted and im saving the old data only to the file.

i want to know how to avoid setPlainText to call focusOutEvent .

Comment: you should set event filter right before calling `setPlainText()` and ignore it. After, remove the filter. See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters

Comment: thanks  im trying your metod and report it to you ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can avoid it but you can introduce a `bool-member` which is set to `false` before you call the `setPlainText` and `true` afterwards. In your `focusOutEvent` you then check the state of the member.

I usually don't like these things that much and consider them somewhat a dirty solution but often it is just an easy, fast and reliable way.

Comment: ok i did it finally with a bool function . but still i feel it is not right way to do .

Comment: I agree. If you find a better solution I'm happy to hear it yo I can use it in the future as well